# Slick SourceCodeGenerator From SQL File

Tags: sql, scala, schema, rdbms, slick

Is there a way to use the Slick SourceCodeGenerator to generate source code from a file of SQL CREATE statements? I know there is a way to connect to a DB and read in the schema, but I want to cut out that step and just give it the file. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick ready meta data via jdbc. If you find a jdbc driver that can do that from a SQL file, you may be in luck. Otherwise, why not use an H2 in-memory database? It has compatibility modes for various SQL dialects. They are limited though. Another option would be using something like this: https://github.com/bgranvea/mysql2h2-converter first to produce an H2 compatible schema file.

We used the following script to load a sql schema from a mysql database, convert it to H2 compatible format and then use it in-memory for tests. You should be able to adapt it.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ''
export IP=192.168.1.123
export user=foobar
export password=secret
export database=foobar
ping -c 1 $IP &&\
echo "" &&\
echo "Server is reachable"
# dump mysql schema for debuggability (ignore in git)
# convert the mysql to h2db using the converter.

## disable foreign key check in begining and enable it in the end. Prevents foreign key errors
echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" > foobar-mysql.sql

## Dump the Db structure and remove the auto_increment so as to set the id column back to 1
mysqldump --compact -u $user -h $IP -d $database -p$password\
|sed 's/CONSTRAINT `_*/CONSTRAINT `/g' \
|sed 's/KEY `_*/KEY `/g' \
|sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//' \
>> foobar-mysql.sql

echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;" >> foobar-mysql.sql &&\

java -jar mysql2h2-converter.jar foobar-mysql.sql \
|perl -0777 -pe 's/([^`]),/\1,\n  /g' \
|perl -0777 -pe 's/\)\);/)\n);/g' \
|perl -0777 -pe 's/(CREATE TABLE [^\(]*\()/\1\n  /g' \
|sed 's/UNSIGNED/unsigned/g' \
|sed 's/float/real/' \
|sed "s/\(int([0-9]*).*\) DEFAULT '\(.*\)'/\1 DEFAULT \2/" \
|sed "s/tinyint(1)/boolean/" \
 > foobar-h2.sql

perl -ne 'print "$ARGV\n" if /.\z/' -- foobar-h2.sql
```